# How to include multiple views in one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm turning a pure HTML website into a small Rails app and have come across an issue.

Currently I have a index.html page and a translation.html page (which displays index in another language). There is currently a link on index.html to translate the page and vice verse.

I have set index.html as the 'show' action, but am unsure how to handle translate.html page. Both will have the same information/Rails form.

Comment: You're probably being downvoted because this question is incredible noob, and doesn't evidence any effort to be self suficient

Comment: Instead of duplicating the page, you could use [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: @Stefan that is the best long-term solution.  Hopefully OP will grow to that level

Answer (score 0):

Make the embed-able content in `translate.html` into a partial, like `_translated.html`.  Then you include the partial `_translated.html` (that's what the "`_`" means; a "partial" view) in each of the `translate.html` and the `index.html` pages.  [Read up on partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), and use a code like

```
render :partial => 'translated'
```

in each of your main view pages.

Comment: It is sufficient to type `render 'translated'` - render use partial in default when executed within view context.

Comment: True, and even though this is explicitly a Rail-4 question, by tagging, I still thought I'd give a reverse-compatible answer.  Thanks, though